# Finding $\mathbb R^2$ for one parameter given covariance matrix and $\mathbb R^2$ for another parameter

Tags: statistics, regression-analysis

Consider the linear regression model with design matrix
$X = [x_1 \mid x_2 \mid \cdots\mid x_p] \in\mathbb R^{n\times p}$. Assume that $x^T_j 1_n = 0$, for $j = 1, \ldots , p$, that is, the columns of $X$ are centered. (Here, and elsewhere $1_n \in\mathbb R^n$ is the vector of all-ones of length $n$). Note that the model does not include an
intercept.

Assume that:

$$
\frac{1}{n}X^TX=\begin{bmatrix}I_{p-1} & z\\z & a^2\end{bmatrix}, z\in R^{p-1}, a^2\in R
$$
where $a^2$ and $z$ are given quantities. Assume that $a^2=10\|z\|^2$.

Let R$^2_j$ be the $R^2$ obtained when regressing x$_j$ onto the rest of covariates $\{x_1, \ldots , x_{j−1}, x_{j+1}, \ldots , x_p\}.$
Find R$^2_p$, that is, the coefficient of determination resulting from regressing $x_p$ onto $\{x_1, \ldots , x_{p−1}\}.$

I'm not really sure how to convert from one $\mathbb R^2$ to another $\mathbb R^2$. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction or towards a formula I can use, as I can't seem to find much helpful information.

Comment: Thank you for the edits.

Comment: Mathematicians write "for all $j\in\{1,\ldots,p\}$" or "for $j=1,\ldots,p,$" (without the word "all") and I edited accordingly. I also put in proper MathJax usage; you can look at how I coded the notation.

Comment: I'm afraid my first comment was hastily written and grossly wrong about the language usage point. See my replacement of it.

Comment: $$ \begin{align} & \text{for all } j\in\{1,\ldots,p\} & & (\text{with the word “all''}) \\ & \text{or} \\ & \text{for } j=1,\ldots,p & & (\text{without the word “all''}) \end{align} $$